# Composite View touch/click handling

Tags: android, listener, android-view, onclicklistener

I created a custom composite View to represent a "card" with multiple areas/images sensitive to clicks. Additionally, this card view will be placed in a larger view (with other card views), and I want to be able to drag and drop the card view within this larger area.

The first thing I noticed was that when the card's internal image views have an onClick handler, the onTouchEvent and its associated listener was NOT being called for the card in the outer view's context. This implies to me that the inner context is consuming the touch event to evaluate the onClick. So I guess I can't make the card view "modular" from that point of view- it will have to implement onTouch in order to allow the onTouch to bubble up to the outer context when it is not a click within the card's view itself?

What is the way that this should be approached, as the above seems like it may not be correct?

I am using API > 4 for this.

Comment: "This implies to me that the inner context is consuming the touch event to evaluate the onClick" -- generally speaking, events bubble up from children to parents. So, if a widget consumes a touch event (including via a click handler), the container holding that widget will not receive the event. "it will have to implement onTouch in order to allow the onTouch to bubble up to the outer context when it is not a click within the card's view itself?" -- I didn't follow that part, sorry. I am not sure why the card view needs a touch event if it is being used elsewhere for a click event.

Comment: I was trying to have an "object oriented" approach, where the CardView component knew how to handle its own internal events- a click on one of its ImageViews, while at the same time, the CardView could be one of several CardViews inside the main activity's view, and in that context a CardView could be touched to drag it. 

I fear there is probably some conflict- how to tell if there is a click/touch on the ImageView inside a cardView, or whether the cardView is being touched to drag it. Is there a better model to use here?

Comment: Well, I haven't dealt with the drag-and-drop stuff yet in Android. I think that I recall seeing some stuff for a child to send fake touch events to a parent to help deal with this. My apologies for not being of greater assistance.